# Make changes on with colors conditional formatted cells

Tags: excel, vba, colors, conditional-formatting

Function of the code is: The letters "SZ" should be placed or deleted by doubleclicking in the cells, EXCEPT where the conditional formatting settings make the fill color to RGB(208, 206, 206): light grey, RGB(189, 215, 238): blue and RGB(242, 228, 214): light rose. I use the OR method to combine these colors in the code. If the user doubleclicks these cells, a message box pops up with the message "Invalid".
Unfortunately with the third color, light rose doesn't work the code. If I delete the row with the color light rose, the code works well. But I want to work it on light rose colored cells, too. What is wrong with the code?
Thank you.
[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = Union(Range("B13:AF17"), _
                    Range("B21:AF25"), _
                    Range("B29:AF33"), _
                    Range("B37:AF41"), _
                    Range("B45:AF49"), _
                    Range("B53:AF57"), _
                    Range("B61:AF65"), _
                    Range("B69:AF73"), _
                    Range("B77:AF81"), _
                    Range("B85:AF89"), _
                    Range("B93:AF97"), _
                    Range("B101:AF105"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, cell) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True ' Cancels the default double-click behavior

        If Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(208, 206, 206) Or _
            Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(189, 215, 238) Or _
            Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 228, 214) _
            Then
            MsgBox "Invalid"
        Else
            ' Place or delete "SZ" for other colors
            If Target.Value = "SZ" Then
                Target.ClearContents
            Else
                Target.Value = "SZ"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/oovGL.png  and https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wM9o.png

Comment: Same. It works fine with me. Are the RGB colors set right in the conditional formatting?

Comment: The first thing to check is that you have the correct rgb values for light rose.  For example, I don't see aan rgbLightRose defined in the xlRGBColor enumeration. As RGB return a value of the MsoRGBType you might want use values from this enumeration rather than RGB directly.

Comment: Below `Cancel = True` place this line: `Debug.Print "R: " & Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Mod 256 & " G: " & Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color \ 256 Mod 256 & " B: " & Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color \ 65536 Mod 256` I get this in return which works fine `R: 242 G: 228 B: 214`